# ObjectDataProvider wpf local type not found

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have had a look but I can not find the answer to this error (That I understand!).

I am working  through this article here [CodeProject Datagrid practical example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples#masterdetail)
and trying to modify the code for my simple CRUD screen in WPF, which I am new to

I believe I am trying to get an object instantiated and used as the datasource to the data grid
but in my mark up on build I get the following error, which I clearly do not understand.

I thought that the objectdataprovider in my xaml key was the class of the CustomerScheduleDataProvider and the type is the constructor, but clearly not, if the example markup it is the **CustomerDataProvider** part of the code is where I have substituted my class name

Can someone please point out what I am missing, many Thanks
Ian

> Type 'local:CustomerScheduleDataProvider' was not found.
>      at MS.Internal.Platform.MemberDocumentValueSerializer`1.ConvertToDocumentValue(ITypeMetadata type, String value, IServiceProvider documentServices)
>      at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlMarkupExtensionPropertyBase.get_Value()
>      at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.DocumentPropertyWrapper.get_Value()
>      at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.InMemory.InMemoryDocumentProperty..ctor(DocumentProperty property, InMemoryDocumentItem item)
>      at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.InMemory.InMemoryDocumentItem.SetUpItem(DocumentItem item)

Here is my mark up and code I have included my references because my experience is these are missed out by the experienced coders and us newbies do not realise which ones we should be using!

```
<Window 

xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
Title="Customer Forecast Input" Height="300" Width="600">

<Window.Resources>
    <!-- create an instance of our DataProvider class -->
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="CustomerScheduleDataProvider"
        ObjectType="{x:Type local:CustomerScheduleDataProvider}"/>

    <!-- define the method which is invoked to obtain our data -->
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="CustomerSchedule"
      ObjectInstance="{StaticResource CustomerScheduleDataProvider}"
      MethodName="GetCustomerSchedules"/>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomerSchedule}}">
    <dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="dataGrid"/>
</DockPanel>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
namespace CustomerForecastInput
{
   public class CustomerScheduleDataProvider
   {
   private SysproCompanyTDataSetTableAdapters.CustomerSchedulesTableAdapter CSadapter;
   private SysproCompanyTDataSet ds;

   public CustomerScheduleDataProvider()
   {
       ds = new SysproCompanyTDataSet();
       CSadapter = new SysproCompanyTDataSetTableAdapters.CustomerSchedulesTableAdapter();
       CSadapter.Fill(ds.CustomerSchedules);
    }
   public DataView GetCustomerSchedules()
   {
       return ds.CustomerSchedules.DefaultView;

   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not declare the namespace in XAML before using it. So put below declaration in your Window tag.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomerForecastInput"
```